# How to check if process is completed?

Tags: php, bash

I have a php script that is currently invoked directly by a webhook. The webhook method was fine up until this past week where the volume of requests is becoming problematic for API rate limits.

What I have been trying to do is make a second PHP file (`$path/webhook-receiver.php`)  to be invoked by webhooks  only when there isn't a process running. I'll be using the process user webb recommended, which is in the invoked script (`$path/event-finance-reporting.php`) it will create a file as the first action, and the delete that file as the last exection.

Before invoking the script the automation will check the directory to make sure it is empty, otherwise it will kick back an error to the user telling them to wait until the current job is completed before submitting another one.

The problem I'm running into now is that both `$command1` and `$command2'. both end up invoking the`$path/webhook-reciever.php`instead of`$path/event-finance-reporting.php`.

```
$command1 = "php -f  $path/event-finance-reporting.php 123456789";
$command2 = "/usr/bin/php -q -f  $path/event-finance-reporting.php 123456789";
```

Anyone know why would be?

Comment: What happens if you try putting `$command = "php -i";` just as a test... ?

Comment: If I leave the `> /dev/null &` there it does nothing. If I take it just runs forever but doesn't display anything. What does "php -i" do?

Comment: `php -i` is the bash equivalent to `php_info();`. I tested it [like this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6d3d36a494ba5da916af7dedd14a551a), and it returned the PID successfully. The problem I believe is that you need to replace `$pids` with `$execute_response`.

Comment: Could you by chance screenshot what the output looks like?

Comment: Also, this may seem like a stupid question, but where is the $file variable coming from, in the `$check_for_running_response`?

Comment: It appears `$file` is useless there and `-C` more or less is also, you can probably just use this and it will return the same info: `ps -o pid=`. — here's [the output](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a270dcd9dff0e435cfb0f5e27b5077c4) I get, the last value displayed would likely be that of the executed command (your script).

Comment: So this is getting all of the pids for my server right now? Or is it only getting the PID of the file that I executed?

Comment: Did you try it with your original `$command`, and what is the output? I would need that info to answer that.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to update the original post with all of this because the comment formatting is a bit hard to read with everything that needs to be put in here. One moment.

Answer (score 1):

The goal it to have only one instance of event-finance-reporting.php run at a time. One strategy is to create a unique lockfile, don't run if it exists, and delete it when it finishes, e.g.,:

```
$lockfilepath = '.../event-finance-reporting.lock';
if(file_exists($lockfilepath)){
  print("try again later");
  exit();
}
touch($lockfilepath);
...
// event-finance-reporting.php code
...
unlink($lockfilepath);
```

You could also do something more complicated in the `if`, such as checking the age of the lockfile, then deleting and ignoring it if it was left behind awhile ago by a crashed instance of `event-finance-reporting.php`.

With this strategy, you also don't need two separate `php`s.

Comment: Now that is just too smart. Thanks for this, and this is exactly what I will implement.

Comment: Could you shed some light as to whey both of my above commands for `$execute_response` seem to running the webhook receiver over and over instead of running the `event-finance-reporting.php`?

Comment: No idea. But I updated answer now that I understand you only want one running instance at a time. If you do decide to allow a limited number of multiple instances, you could do the first thing I said, and then count the number of files in the directory to see the number of unfinished instances.